# Find the solution of the initial value problem and determine the breaking time. Find all shock wave solutions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the solution of the initial value problem $u_t(x,t)+u(x,t)u_x(x,t)=0$ with $u(x,0)=\begin{cases} 2 &\text{if } x<0\\ 1 &\text{if } 0\leq x<1\\ 0 &\text{if } x\geq1\end{cases}$.  Determine the breaking time of the solution and find all shock wave solutions.

I got $u(x,t)=\begin{cases} 2 &\text{if } x<0\\ 1 &\text{if } 0\leq x<1\\ 0 &\text{if } x\geq1\end{cases}$, which is the same as the initial condition given.  I don't what I did wrong, if that's actually right. And I have no idea about the next parts. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are solving the Burgers equation with piecewise constant initial data. The main concepts are:

1. From every point $(x_0,0)$ emanates a characteristic line with equation $x=x_0+tu(x_0,0)$
2. Characteristic lines either continue indefinitely or terminate at a shock wave.
3. Shock wave forms when an interval with velocity $v_1$ is positioned immediately to the left of an interval with velocity $v_2$, where $v_1>v_2$.
4. Shock wave propagates at the speed of $(v_1+v_2)/2$.

In your situation, two shock waves are formed immediately: one starting at $0$ and one starting at $1$. According to the above, their equations are $x=t/2$ and $x=1+3t/2$. These shock waves are shown in red below (the $x$ axis is horizontal, $t$ axis is vertical.) In between them, the solution takes the values $2,1,0$ left to right. The lines in blue are characteristic lines.

The shock wave will meet eventually (you can figure out when and where). From that point on, only the velocities $2$ and $0$ are present in the picture. They are separated by a shock wave propagating  at the speed of $(2+0)/2 = 1$.

[image: sketch]